# Common title to many subplots in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am making a chart in matplotlib and I have many subplots in it each of them with a different title, but on the top I also want to a put a title to the whole chart. How this can be done?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can use the [`pyplot.suptitle`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.suptitle.html) command to add a *centered title to the figure* in addition to sub plot titles.